# page.js cancel page leaving

Tags: javascript, url-routing, page.js

On a **single page application**, the client is editing a big form at

`localhost/#!/product/123/edit`

- He navigates away, I want to display a confirm dialog "Are you sure to leave?" [OK] [Cancel]. If he click on [Cancel] he must stay with the form.
- Here is my current implementation

`page.exit('*', function (ctx, next) {
        if (form is editing and not submitted) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave")) {
                next(); //user click OK -> leave
            }
        }
        else {
            next(); //nothing changed on the form => leave
        }
    });`

The problem: each time I click on a link ('/foo') and cancel the leaving. The page content (my big form) stay untouched but `page.js` will still `pushState('/foo')` and the window.location changes to '/foo' which is no longer corresponding with the page

how can we really cancel the pushState, and left the address bar stay untouched at `localhost/#!/product/123/edit`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did is set

context.handled = false;

when I raise the dialog (a bootstrap modal).
Works fine, except for a small glitch: If I modify some input field, then attempt navigation to clicking a link, then choose to stay in the page, then if I hit the same link, no action is triggered. Other links work fine.

See the [corresponding issue in github](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/issues/320).